# Get the sum by comparing between two tables

Tags: mysql

I have to tables ProdBiscuit As tb and StockData As sd , I have to get the sum of the quantity in StockData (quantite) with the condition of if (sd.status>0 AND sd.prodid = tb.id AND sd.matcuisine = 3)

Here is my sql query

```
 SELECT tb.id, tb.nom, tb.proddate, tb.qty, tb.stockrecno 
 FROM ProdBiscuit AS tb
 JOIN 

(SELECT id, prodid, matcuisine, status, SUM(quantite) AS rq FROM StockData) AS sd
 ON (tb.id = sd.prodid AND sd.status > 0 AND sd.matcuisine = 3) LIMIT 25 OFFSET @Myid
```

This gives me no rows at all ?

There is only 3 rows in ProdBiscuit and 11 rows in Stockdata and there is only 2 rows in StockData good with the condition.

And as shown in the picture there is only two rows which give the condition.

[Image of two tables](http://www.turcguide.com/stack/mysql5.jpg)

What is wrong in my query ?

PS: The green lines on the image shows the condition in my query.

Comment: What is the value of `@Myid`

Comment: The first problem I can see is the query that you are joining to does not have a group by statement:  You should have `GROUP BY id, prodid, matcuisine, status` after `FROM StockData`

Comment: @Lock Myid is an index for displaying at a time 25 rows begining from Myid. As there is only 3 row its does not affect the query.

Comment: @AgRizzo after grouping as you told it reads the data but it does not recognize the"rq" as it's defined ?? Before grouping reader was not reading the data.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ might have been more useful than the pictures. You are apparently not selecting anything from `sd`. You should be able to avoid the subquery, and use a `GROUP BY` instead.

Comment: @MvG I did it in sqlfiddle here is the link of the result http://www.turcguide.com/stack/query.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this.  If you aren't getting the results you want, go to SQLFiddle.com and create sample tables with data to make it easier to figure out what you want.

```
SELECT tb.id, tb.nom, tb.proddate, tb.qty, tb.stockrecno, SUM(sd.quanite)
FROM ProdBiscuit AS tb
JOIN StockData AS sd
  ON tb.id = sd.prodid
WHERE sd.status > 0 AND sd.matcuisine = 3
GROUP BY tb.id, tb.nom, tb.proddate, tb.qty, tb.stockrecno
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. I forgot an paranthesis that is why I could not get the result of your query thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tb.id, tb.nom, tb.proddate, tb.qty, tb.stockrecno, SUM(quantite)  As rq

FROM ProdBiscuit AS tb 

JOIN StockData AS sd  ON (tb.id = sd.prodid AND sd.status > 0 AND sd.matcuisine = 3)
OR (tb.id = sd.prodid AND sd.status = 0 AND sd.matcuisine = 3)  
GROUP BY tb.id, tb.nom, tb.proddate, tb.qty, tb.stockrecno
```

This query gives me this

```
ID  NOM                    QTY      RQ
1   Biscuit Chocolat       100      100
2   Biscuit Moutarde       120      226
3   Biscuit Pain Epice     100      100
```

AND Happy End with the help of @AgRizzo I did a little modification and add for having the exact display:

```
SELECT tb.id, tb.nom, tb.proddate, tb.qty, tb.stockrecno, 

SUM(IF((status>0 AND tb.id=sd.prodid),quantite,0))  As rq FROM ProdBiscuit AS tb 

JOIN StockData AS sd  ON (tb.id = sd.prodid AND sd.status > 0 AND sd.matcuisine = 3)
OR (tb.id = sd.prodid AND sd.status = 0 AND sd.matcuisine = 3)  
GROUP BY tb.id, tb.nom, tb.proddate, tb.qty, tb.stockrecno



ID  NOM                    QTY      RQ
1   Biscuit Chocolat       100      100
2   Biscuit Moutarde       120       14
3   Biscuit Pain Epice     100      100

Code for displaying the "rq" is:

QtyLst.Items.Add((Convert.ToInt16(reader["qty"])- Convert.ToInt16(reader["rq"])).ToString());
```